# Why is it not possible to create a Microsoft email with "live.com" domain anymore?

Tags: outlook.com

Why is it not possible to create a Microsoft email with "live.com" domain anymore?

Looking at options only "outlook.com" and "hotmail.com" are available. What is the reason? Earlier the "live.com" was available. Will "live.com" emails be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, email services from live.com have been discontinued. If you already have one, they will remain active and no end-date has been published to my knowledge for them being deleted. However, new signups have been disabled for some time in favour of outlook.com and Office365.

Comment: Should I switch to outlook.com to be future proof ? Will live.com be reactivated ?

Comment: I doubt it will be reactivated at any point.  Microsoft are trying to progress their technology, not regress (although others will argue they're managing it anyway!).  There will most likely be no plans to switch off teh service for years yet - it still has millions of users!  That said, outlook.com is the way to go for definite future proofing